# Open WPF window on button click from a form window

Tags: c#

Is it possible if I have a window form and upon a click event it opens a window in WPF using C# in Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes it is. Also have in mind it is Visual and not Virtual Studio

Answer (score 0):

Just add a wpf project, reference it, and open it in code like

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
            new WpfApplication1.MainWindow().Show();
        }
```

Where MainWindow is your window in the WpfApplication1 project.
You need a reference to PresentationCore, Windowsbase and Presentationframework